# event.stopPropagation() is not worknig?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented click event on window and on specific element. I want to stop window click  event propagation on particular element click as mentioned below but it is not working. I am not sure what wrong I am doing here.

```js
$('.dropdown-container').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
  var selectElement = '.dropdown-container > select';
  if($(selectElement).hasClass('actionDD')){
    $(selectElement+'.actionDD').toggleClass('special');
  }
  else if($(selectElement).hasClass('countryDD')) {
    $(selectElement+'.countryDD').toggleClass('special');
  }
  $('.fa-chevron-down.importC, .fa-chevron-down.exportC ').removeClass('special');
});
      
$(window).click(function(event){
  console.log('window event clicked');
  $('.dropdown-container, .fa-chevron-down.importC, .fa-chevron-down.exportC').removeClass('special');
});
```

Comment: TYPO: `e.stopPropagation()` to `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: As above, or `.click(function(e) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the typos, if your selects are not nested just do this

```js
$('.dropdown-container').on("click", "select", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()

  if($(this).is('.actionDD') || $(this).is('.countryDD')) { 
    $(this).toggleClass('special');
  }
  $('.fa-chevron-down.importC, .fa-chevron-down.exportC ').removeClass('special');
});
      
$(window).on("click", function(e){
  console.log('window event clicked');
  $('.dropdown-container, .fa-chevron-down.importC, .fa-chevron-down.exportC').removeClass('special');
});
```

Please post your HTML since this works:

```js
$('.dropdown-container').on("click", "select", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  if ($(this).is('.actionDD') || $(this).is('.countryDD')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('special');
  }
});

$(window).on("click", function(e) {
  console.log('window event clicked');
});
```

```css
.special {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <select class="actionDD">
    <option>Click</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working, still I am getting "window event clicked" on console.

Comment: Please see my update. We need to see your HTML

Comment: Yes, it is working indeed. Thanks mplungjan